# In Java 1.6 File.renameTo() atomic on linux?

Tags: java, linux, posix, rename, atomic

As the title says, in Java 1.6 `File.renameTo()` an atomic operation on POSIX linux?

According to [this link](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename), the rename operation in POSIX Linux is atomic, however, does it hold `true` for `File.renameTo`?

Comment: "According to these links" <-- which links?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Linux, the rename is atomic *if and only if* the source path and target path are under the same *mount point* (not filesystem).

`File.renameTo()` is essentially a call to `rename(2)` under Linux, so you'll have to test for its return value to see if the file could be renamed.

With Java 7, drop `File`, instead use:

```
Files.move(src, dst, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
```

---

Here is an example. On my system, `/home` is a different mount point to `/`, so the first rename will succeed (same filesystem), the second rename fails:

```
fge@alustriel:~/tmp/t$ cat Rename.java 
import java.io.File;

public final class Rename
{
    private Rename()
    {
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
    {
        final File f1 = new File("/home/fge/tmp/t/foo");
        final File f2 = new File("/home/fge/tmp/t/bar");
        final File f3 = new File("/tmp/foo");

        if (f1.renameTo(f2))
            f2.renameTo(f3);
    }
}

fge@alustriel:~/tmp/t$ javac Rename.java
fge@alustriel:~/tmp/t$ strace -ff -o TRACE java Rename
fge@alustriel:~/tmp/t$ grep -w rename TRACE.*
TRACE.17107:rename("/home/fge/tmp/t/foo", "/home/fge/tmp/t/bar") = 0
TRACE.17107:rename("/home/fge/tmp/t/bar", "/tmp/foo") = -1 EXDEV (Invalid cross-device link)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you have any references to support that?

Comment: Thanks. again. That's what I assumed that File.renameTo was using, but I can't find a link to support that statement. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Also, you can `strace` a simple main program which does a `.renameTo()`.

Comment: See edit: I provided a sample Java file and an associated trace